# How to get the specific char in char list or List<char>

Tags: c#, .net, char

```
List<char> pc = new List<char>();
            pc.Add('?');
            pc.Add(';');
            pc.Add(',');

return pc.Contains(Convert.ToChar(temp)) ? pc[Convert.ToChar(temp)].ToString() : null;
```

(above code in the method which return string)

Normally in string list I get any specific value from List[] but in this it's changing the char into int.

example: pc['?'] == pc[63] due to this ArgumentOutOfRangeException occur.

So, how I get the specific char from my char list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to return here? It looks like you need to return `temp` rather than `pc[Convert.ToChar(temp)].ToString()`?

Comment: Thanks I haven't thought in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A char holds an integral value, but the index of your list is not equal to the value of the char it's holding. Your list looks like this, with `[index] => value`:

```
[0] => 63
[1] => 59
[2] => 44
```

You'll have to scan the list:

```
var charToFind = Convert.ToChar(temp);
char? match = pc.FirstOrDefault(c => c == charToFind);
```

If you want to know the index, ask for the index:

```
int index = pc.IndexOf(charToFind); // -1 for not found
```

But then if you have the desired char in `temp` (or `charToFind`) already, there's no need to obtain it from the list again, you can just return the char if it's present in the list:

```
return pc.Contains(charToFind) ? charToFind.ToString() : null;
```